# What does Jenkins see when it reads the contents of a Bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins is installed in a local server inside our local network.  It needs to connect to a Bitbucket Server instance which is also running in our local network.

We created a **Bitbucket Team/Project** in Jenkins and configured it to reach out to the Bitbucket server instance.  When the **Bitbucket Team/Project** runs in Jenkins, it is able to successfully connect to the correct repository in the local instance of Bitbucket Server.  It is able to list the names of each branch in the linked Bitbucket repository.  But it cannot find the Jenkinsfile.

My main question: How can I find out what Jenkins actually sees in the directory structure when it looks for the Jenkinsfile? Knowing what Jenkins sees would make it a lot easier to figure out what syntax to enter for the configuration.

The code is downloaded from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/jenkins-docs/simple-python-pyinstaller-app).  As you can see, the Jenkinsfile is located in the `jenkins/Jenkinsfile` directory, even though Jenkins does not seem to be able to find it at that location.  We get a similar error when we configure Jenkins to look for the Jenkinsfile at `Jenkinsfile` instead of at `jenkins/Jenkinsfile`.

Here are the logs that are generated when the **Bitbucket Team/Project** runs:

```
Started
[Thu Apr 19 22:20:10 GMT 2018] Starting organization scan...
[Thu Apr 19 22:20:10 GMT 2018] Updating actions...
Looking up team details of JPE...
Connecting to http://<local-bitbucket-server-ip>:7990 using CredentialName/******
Team: Jenkins Pipeline Examples
[Thu Apr 19 22:20:10 GMT 2018] Consulting Bitbucket Team/Project
Connecting to http://<local-bitbucket-server-ip>:7990 using CredentialName/******
Looking up repositories of team JPE
Proposing simple-python-pyinstaller-app
Connecting to http://<local-bitbucket-server-ip>:7990 using CredentialName/******
Repository type: Git
Looking up JPE/simple-python-pyinstaller-app for branches
Checking branch py-issue-branch-example from JPE/simple-python-pyinstaller-app
      ‘jenkins/Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Skipped
Checking branch master from JPE/simple-python-pyinstaller-app
      ‘jenkins/Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Skipped
Checking branch feature/py-feature-branch-example from JPE/simple-python-pyinstaller-app
      ‘jenkins/Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Skipped

  3 branches were processed
Looking up JPE/simple-python-pyinstaller-app for pull requests

  0 pull requests were processed
1 repositories were processed
[Thu Apr 19 22:20:10 GMT 2018] Finished organization scan. Scan took 0.21 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go to your Jenkins job you should be able to view the workspace. This is where it checks out the repository and that will show you exactly what Jenkins "sees".

Jenkins sets an environment variable $WORKSPACE which is the absolute path to the workspace directory. This may help you to make sure you are where you want to be when searching for files.

Comment: How do I go to the Jenkins job?  Navigating to **Project Name > Build History** results in a `404 Error`

Comment: Also, I thought the job logs were what I posted at the end of the OP above, and they do not indicate any truth about the location of the `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: A workaround was to create a fresh empty Bitbucket repo with a `Jenkinsfile` in its root directory, then to create a fresh empty **Bitbucket Team/Project** in Jenkins and link it to the new Bitbucket repo.  ...  But this workaround does not answer the OP that asks what Jenkins sees at this point in the process.  Instead, this workaround simply eliminates confounding factors.

Comment: That's very strange that your build history gave you a 404. But generally on the main page for a project there will be a link to view your Workspace. That's what I was referring to.